# Evaluate in PhantomJS doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have a problem with JavaScript magic. When I execute this code:

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url="http://google.com";
page.open(url, function (status){
  if (status!== "success") {
    console.log("Fail to load: "+url)
  }else{
    console.log('1');
    page.evaluate(function() {
      console.log('2');
      });   
    console.log('3');
  }
phantom.exit();
});
```

console have only 1 and 3 and no 2. Can anyone say why?

If I paste after my code [DOM manipulation example](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart#DOM_Manipulation) (but it never execute) I have my two. Did I forget something important?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PhantomJS won't log console messages in .evaluate() statements by default.  Just include

```
page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};
```

See this page for more details/in-depth example:

http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart#Code_Evaluation

Answer (score 5):

From [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart)

> Any console message from a web page, including from the code inside
>   evaluate(), will not be displayed by default. To override this
>   behavior, use the onConsoleMessage callback.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want select logs to come through, you can return the value that you'd like to print.

For example:

```
console.log(page.evaluate(function() {
    return '2';
});
```